# Python 3 integer addresses

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, python-internals

```
x=300
y=300
print(id(x),id(y))
a=[300,300]
print(id(a[0]),id(a[1]))
```

On executing above code I get different addresses for `x` and `y` but the same address for `a[0]` and `a[1]`. Can anyone tell me why that is happening?

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow !!! Open a new python interpreter and then try the example on that. It will show same address for `x` and `y`.

Comment: Which python compiler I have to use @Chandila07 I am already using python IDLE 3.6

Comment: You can check my answer.

Comment: I get a different id for `x` and `y` using Python 3.6.5 (command line).

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at below example:

```
>>> a=256
>>> b=256
>>> print(id(a),id(b))
(31765012, 31765012)
>>> 
>>> c=257
>>> d=257
>>> print(id(c),id(d))
(44492764, 44471284)
>>>
```

This will help you understand the unexpected behavior for integers. Whenever you create a int in range `-5` to `256` you actually just get back a reference to the existing object. This is called **Integer Caching** in python.

In CPython, the C-API function that handles creating a new int object is `PyLong_FromLong(long v)`. see the documentation on [this link](http://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/long.html)

EDIT: Now coming to the list. For the same list elements (larger integers) you are getting same id's because list is created at once or you can say in one go.

You can achieve similar behavior with integers as well, see below example with parallel assignment.

```
>>>
>>> a,b = 300,300
>>>
>>> print(id(a),id(b))
(36132288, 36132288)
>>>
```

Hope this will clear your doubts.

Comment: Interesting but elaborating more would be nice.

Comment: Nice example, +1. But I think you've only answered half the question. Maybe you can also show why `a[0]` and `a[1]` are the same address as requested by the OP.

Comment: Thanks @MattMessersmith see my edited answer for more information.

Comment: Thanks @BramVanroy, see my edited answer, hope this will help more understanding.

Comment: @Chandila07 Thanks for the clarification